# Continuar si es una letra

Tags: java, java-util-scanner

Buenas,
Me preguntaba si es posible obligar al usuario a poner una letra o no avanzara.
Con un int sería algo así:

```
int x = 0;
while (x < 1){
    if(lector.hasNextInt){
        int numero = lector.nextInt();
        x++;
    }
}
```

He estado buscando como hacerlo con una letra pero no lo encuentro.

Gracias.

Comment: En tu ejemplo, no veo que estés obligando al usuario a entrar un int. Mas bien, lo que veo es que si el usuario no entra un número, vas a entrar en un ciclo infinito.

Comment: Cierto pero en cierta forma tambien lo estás obligando. Me gustaria saber si hay alguna forma de hacer lo mismo con una letra.

Comment: no, porque una vez que entras en el ciclo infinito, no le vuelves a dar oportunidad al usuario de entrar un número. No hay salida. Y el problema es que siendo que el ejemplo no funciona bien, entonces no me queda claro cual comportamiento deseas en realidad.

Comment: Cierto. Faltaria la linea de lector.next();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí te dejo un código que acabo de hacer, espero que te sirva, es una manera cutre pero rápida y eficaz

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean salir=false;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(salir == false) {
        System.out.println("Pulsa y para continuar");

        char letraUsuario = input.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);

        if(letraUsuario == 'y') {
            System.out.println("Puedes continuar");
            salir = true;
        }else {
            System.out.println("La letra no es adecuada, vuelve a introducir una letra");
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias! Ahora lo probaré.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes comparar contra una expresión regular

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String sTexto;
String pattern = "[a-zA-Z]";
do {
  System.out.println("Ingrese una letra");
  sTexto = br.readLine();
} while(!sTexto.matches(pattern));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!